# The differences between the meaning of "with/because of/about/of/on" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning, word-difference

> 1. I am tired **with** this project.
> 2. I am tired **because of** this project.
> 3. I am tired **about** this project.
> 4. I am tired **of** this project.
> 5. I am tired **on** this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This suggests that you have been working on the project and are **sick of it**. Perhaps you wish to stop working on it or maybe you wish to start a new project.
2. This explicitly states that the project is the **reason** for your tiredness. It suggests that you have been working on it for a long time or the work is stressful.
3. This does not make sense to me.
4. This is essentially the same as number 1 but more explicit and more commonly heard.
5. This does not make sense. If I had to comprehend it, it sounds like you are physically lying on top of the project.